# Salt pillar setup correct but apache-formula keeps generating defalt configuration

Tags: salt-stack

im playing around with saltstack and wanted to use the apache-formula from github/saltstack-formulas.

my pillar looks like following:

top.sls

```
base:
  'ubuntu-xenial-salt':
    - systems.ubuntu-xenial-salt
```

systems/ubuntu-xenial-salt.sls

```
include:
  - setups.apache.prod

apache:
  sites:
    ubuntu-salt-xenial:
      enabled: True
      template_file: salt://apache/vhosts/standard.tmpl
      template_engine: jinja

      interface: '*'
      port: '80'

      exclude_listen_directive: True # Do not add a Listen directive in httpd.conf

      ServerName: ubuntu-salt-xenial
      ServerAlias: ubuntu-salt-xenial

      ServerAdmin: minion@ubuntu-salt-xenial.com

      LogLevel: debug
      ErrorLog: /var/log/apache2/example.com-error.log
      CustomLog: /var/log/apache2/example.com-access.log

      DocumentRoot: /var/www/ubuntu-salt-xenial/

      Directory:
        default:
          Options: -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
          Require: all granted
          AllowOverride: None
```

setups/apache/prod.sls

```
include:
  - applications.apache

# ``apache`` formula configuration:
apache:
  register-site:
    # any name as an array index, and you can duplicate this section
    UNIQUE_VALUE_HERE:
      name: 'PROD'
      path: 'salt://path/to/sites-available/conf/file'
      state: 'enabled'
      # Optional - use managed file as Jinja Template
      #template: true
      #defaults:
      #  custom_var: "default value"

  modules:
    enabled:  # List modules to enable
      - rewrite
      - ssl
    disabled:  # List modules to disable
      - ldap

  # KeepAlive: Whether or not to allow persistent connections (more than
  # one request per connection). Set to "Off" to deactivate.
  keepalive: 'On'

  security:
    # can be Full | OS | Minimal | Minor | Major | Prod
    # where Full conveys the most information, and Prod the least.
    ServerTokens: Prod

  # ``apache.mod_remoteip`` formula additional configuration:
  mod_remoteip:
    RemoteIPHeader: X-Forwarded-For
    RemoteIPTrustedProxy:
      - 10.0.8.0/24
      - 127.0.0.1

  # ``apache.mod_security`` formula additional configuration:
  mod_security:
    crs_install: True
    # If not set, default distro's configuration is installed as is
    manage_config: True
    sec_rule_engine: 'On'
    sec_request_body_access: 'On'
    sec_request_body_limit: '14000000'
    sec_request_body_no_files_limit: '114002'
    sec_request_body_in_memory_limit: '114002'
    sec_request_body_limit_action: 'Reject'
    sec_pcre_match_limit: '15000'
    sec_pcre_match_limit_recursion: '15000'
    sec_debug_log_level: '3'

    rules:
      enabled:
      modsecurity_crs_10_setup.conf:
        rule_set: ''
        enabled: True
      modsecurity_crs_20_protocol_violations.conf:
        rule_set: 'base_rules'
        enabled: False

    custom_rule_files:
      # any name as an array index, and you can duplicate this section
      UNIQUE_VALUE_HERE:
        file: 'PROD'
        path: 'salt://path/to/modsecurity/custom/file'
        enabled: True
```

applications/apache.sls

```
apache:
  lookup:
    version: '2.4'
    default_charset: 'UTF-8'

    global:
      AllowEncodedSlashes: 'On'

    name_virtual_hosts:
      - interface: '*'
        port: 80
      - interface: '*'
        port: 443
```

Using this pillar configuration and calling highstate for my minion ubuntu-xenial-salt run without any error, however the setup is not the same as declared in the pillar:

for example:

- the enabled rewrite module is not there.
- the virtual-host config is not as setup in the pillar.

everything seems to be pretty much standard configuration from example.pillar.

When i call

```
salt 'ubuntu-xenial-salt' pillar.data
```

i get the pillar data just like i modified it... i cant understand what is happening...

```
ubuntu-xenial-salt:
    ----------
    apache:
        ----------
        keepalive:
            On
        lookup:
            ----------
            default_charset:
                UTF-8
            global:
                ----------
                AllowEncodedSlashes:
                    On
            name_virtual_hosts:
                |_
                  ----------
                  interface:
                      *
                  port:
                      80
                |_
                  ----------
                  interface:
                      *
                  port:
                      443
            version:
                2.4
        mod_remoteip:
            ----------
            RemoteIPHeader:
                X-Forwarded-For
            RemoteIPTrustedProxy:
                - 10.0.8.0/24
                - 127.0.0.1
        mod_security:
            ----------
            crs_install:
                True
            custom_rule_files:
                ----------
                UNIQUE_VALUE_HERE:
                    ----------
                    enabled:
                        True
                    file:
                        PROD
                    path:
                        salt://path/to/modsecurity/custom/file
            manage_config:
                True
            rules:
                ----------
                enabled:
                    None
                modsecurity_crs_10_setup.conf:
                    ----------
                    enabled:
                        True
                    rule_set:
                modsecurity_crs_20_protocol_violations.conf:
                    ----------
                    enabled:
                        False
                    rule_set:
                        base_rules
            sec_debug_log_level:
                3
            sec_pcre_match_limit:
                15000
            sec_pcre_match_limit_recursion:
                15000
            sec_request_body_access:
                On
            sec_request_body_in_memory_limit:
                114002
            sec_request_body_limit:
                14000000
            sec_request_body_limit_action:
                Reject
            sec_request_body_no_files_limit:
                114002
            sec_rule_engine:
                On
        modules:
            ----------
            disabled:
                - ldap
            enabled:
                - ssl
                - rewrite
        register-site:
            ----------
            UNIQUE_VALUE_HERE:
                ----------
                name:
                    PROD
                path:
                    salt://path/to/sites-available/conf/file
                state:
                    enabled
        security:
            ----------
            ServerTokens:
                Prod
        sites:
            ----------
            ubuntu-salt-xenial:
                ----------
                CustomLog:
                    /var/log/apache2/example.com-access.log
                Directory:
                    ----------
                    default:
                        ----------
                        AllowOverride:
                            None
                        Options:
                            -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
                        Require:
                            all granted
                DocumentRoot:
                    /var/www/ubuntu-salt-xenial/
                ErrorLog:
                    /var/log/apache2/example.com-error.log
                LogLevel:
                    debug
                ServerAdmin:
                    minion@ubuntu-salt-xenial.com
                ServerAlias:
                    ubuntu-salt-xenial
                ServerName:
                    ubuntu-salt-xenial
                enabled:
                    True
                exclude_listen_directive:
                    True
                interface:
                    *
                port:
                    80
                template_engine:
                    jinja
                template_file:
                    salt://apache/vhosts/standard.tmpl
```

Do someone knows what's happening here and can help me get it running?

Comment: Can you please link to the exact apache-formula you used? is it this one https://github.com/saltstack-formulas/apache-formula? also please show your top.sls file that is used for highstate.

Comment: Hi Alex, thx for trying to help me out. It is the formula you linked. My top sls file looks pretty standard:

    base:
      'ubuntu-xenial-salt':
         - apache

Comment: I'm wodering after seeing this configuration about setting envirment variables , really i can't find how to do that.